# When to skip verify_authenticity_token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Why would people skip the verification and increase the security vulnerability of their app?  Is it beneficial to disable it on pages that have only GET requests?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CRSF check is already skipped for GET request in rails

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html

> 3.1 CSRF Countermeasures
>        — First, as is required by the W3C, use GET and POST appropriately. Secondly, a security token in non-GET requests will protect your application from CSRF.

You can see the method itself as well.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/RequestForgeryProtection.html#method-i-verify_authenticity_token

```
 .... Also, GET requests are not protected as these should be idempotent. ....

 verified_request?()
   Returns true or false if a request is verified. Checks:
   is it a GET request? Gets should be safe and idempotent
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have cross domain application you could have errors with authtoken verifying and you can disable it, but of course your application won't be secure. In rails 3 there are special methods for cross domain solution in out of box

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Do you know if there are there any benefits (for example performance benefits) to skipping the verification on pages that only have GET requests?

Comment: You can edit in application_controller line: `protect_from_forgery :except => [:index, :show]`